# Почему функция не работает на живом сайте, хотя работала в локальном сайте?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не могу понять, почему функция вывода различных записей работает на локальном сайте, но не работает на живом сайте? Вот например эта:

```
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $params = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $current_page
  );
  query_posts($params);
  $wp_query -> is_archive = true;
  $wp_query -> is_home = false;
  while(have_posts()): the_post();
    get_template_part( 'post-small' );
  endwhile;
```

или:

```
$team = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'team'));
  if($team->have_posts()):
    while($team->have_posts()):$team->the_post();
      get_template_part('team', get_post_format('team'));
    endwhile;
  endif;
  wp_reset_query();
```

Версия PHP на обеих 5.5. В чем дело, кто знает?

Comment: Во-первых, у вас в примерах много разных функций. Какая из них не работает? Что подразумевается под "не работает" - выдает не то\не выдает результат\не исполняется? Что должна она делать? Что пишет лог ошибок?

Comment: В первом куске кода должны выводиться посты типа Новости. На локальном сайте они выводятся корректно, а когда заливаю на живой сайт, не выводит посты вообще, то есть этот блок пустой. Логи я так и не смог активировать, хотя в конфиге установил true на wp debug. Логи не выводятся на сайте.

Comment: Тогда дебажте это построчно. Например, у вас есть проверка if($team->have_posts()) - а может быть на втором сервере почему-то возвращается false? Если все верно, переходите к другой строчке и смотрите что получаете на каждом шаге цикла while и так далее. Вам необходимо найти тот момент на котором происходит ошибка или некорретные действия.

Comment: А базу-то перенесли?

Comment: А все ли нужные модули php активированы?